# outputting a struct variable that's inside a unordered map

Tags: c++, struct, output, unordered

Does anybody know how to output a struct variable that it's inside a unordered map.how could i get dictionary->word for example

```
typedef struct dictionary{ 
std::string word; 
unsigned char hash[20]; 
std::string hex;
 } a_dictionary;

 typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, dictionary*> Mymap;

 std::unordered_map<std::string, dictionary* >::const_iterator got = c1.find(line);
                    if(out.is_open())
                    {
                        if ( got == c1.end() )
                        {
                        out << "????";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        out << got->first << " , ";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `second` member of the iterator is your pointer to the `a_dictionary` structure, so just access it like you would a normal structure pointer:

```
out << got->first << " , " << got->second->word;
```